# How to conditionally display in Vue, only if Firestore field value matches a specific string value?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, conditional-formatting

The Firestore database field (`reviewPrivacy` in the `review` collection) is of string type, populated from a Vue form entry (radio) with one of three three possible answers (values): `keepFullyPrivate` being among them.

I'm trying to only display `<h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2>` if the value of `review.reviewPrivacy` is `keepFullyPrivate`.

Once this is working, I'll add a `v-if-else` and then `v-else` options, displaying different content for each.

My code is below.

There aren't any errors flagged in VSC, but it doesn't matter what the value of  `review.reviewPrivacy` is - the text in the `<h2>` tags always displays, regardless of whether or not it's equal to `keepFullyPrivate`

```
<div v-if="('review.reviewPrivacy', '==', 'keepFullyPrivate')"><h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2></div>
```

Update (additional info):

- I'm using Vue version 3.2.1
- The data from Firestore is fetching correctly. For example, in the same parent  as the code above, this line `<p> Privacy choice for this review: {{ review.reviewPrivacy }} </p>` results in the following text in the DOM: *Privacy choice for this review: postAnonPublic*, which is the `v-else-if` condition.

2nd update: code as a full block, as requested in comments:

```
<div class="review-detailZ">
<div> <!-- BEGIN main (left-hand) column -->
  <p> Privacy choice for this review: {{ review.reviewPrivacy }} </p>
  <br />
   
  <!-- Using Vue version 3.2.1 -->
          
   <div v-if="('review.reviewPrivacy', '==', 'keepFullyPrivate')"><h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2></div>
   <div v-else-if="('review.reviewPrivacy', '==', 'postAnonPublic')"><h2>Incognito - review by{{ review.userName }}</h2></div> 
   <div v-else><h2>Reviewer chose to be fully public - full name is {{ review.userFirstName }} {{ review.userLastName }}</h2></div>
   
  <br />
  <p>Created {{ review.createdAt }} days ago</p>
  <br />
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's wrong because the code is split in different section. Can you share the complete complete (a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) ?

Comment: Didn't `v-if="review.reviewPrivacy === keepFullyPrivate">` and `v-else-if="review.reviewPrivacy === 'postAnonPublic'"` work? Had you tried restarting Vue server after making this change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('review.reviewPrivacy', '==', 'keepFullyPrivate')` is just a comma separated group of strings, and it evaluates to the last string: `'keepFullyPrivate'`, so your markup becomes `v-if="'keepFullyPrivate'"`, which is always truthy. Therefore, the `div` and its `h2` are always rendered.

The correct expression to compare `review.reviewPrivacy` to `'keepFullyPrivate'` is:

```js
review.reviewPrivacy == 'keepFullyPrivate'

// or even better:
review.reviewPrivacy === 'keepFullyPrivate'
```

It's good practice to use triple-equals (`===`) for a [strict comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons?page=2&tab=Votes).

So the end result should be:

```html
<div v-if="review.reviewPrivacy === 'keepFullyPrivate'"><h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2></div>
```

Comment: Happy it worked for you. Restarting the dev server isn't normally needed. Out of curiosity, what dev server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    review: { reviewPrivacy:0 },
    keepFullyPrivate:0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-if="review.reviewPrivacy == keepFullyPrivate">
   <h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2>
</div>
<div v-else>
<h2>else part</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @k-sridhar-reddy. I tried your solution and it did not work for me at the time, BUT I had failed to take the important step of restarting the Vue server. once I did this, Tony19's solution worked (and your may also work, but I haven't texted it). Best, -M

Comment: @MarkGavagan Thank you.., actually 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    review: { reviewPrivacy:0 },
    keepFullyPrivate:'keepFullyPrivate' ---> //inplace of zero you need to place it is another way 
  }
})
happy to see you happy

Comment: Gracias, @k-sridhar-reddy

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this:

A) You can create a computed property "showSectionX ()" which does the comparison:

```js
[...]

<div v-if="showSectionX"><h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2></div>

[...]

computed: {
  showSectionX () {
    return this.review.reviewPrivacy === 'keepFullyPrivate'
  }
}

[...]
```

Instead if `X` you should of course use a word that describes the purpose of this section.

B) you can do the comparison directly in the v-if:

```js
[...]

<div v-if="review.reviewPrivacy === 'keepFullyPrivate'"><h2>The reviewer's identity is private</h2></div>

[...]
```

I guess the latter is what you were trying to do but used the wrong syntax.

Comment: Thank you @Fred. Just before you posted your solution, I used advice by Dharmaraj to correctly implement Tony19's solution, which works perfectly. Best, -M

Comment: If you are using this comparison in different places in your View or Component, I would advice for a computed property to avoid duplication.

Comment: Gracias @Fred. Will do!